# Как создать независимое окно через Qt?

Tags: c++, qt

### Что у меня есть

Основное окно Qt

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  QApplication a(argc, argv);

  MainWindow w;
  w.showMaximized();

  return a.exec();
}
```

Бывает, что при отладке `MainWindow` мне нужно поставить точку остановки (например в цикле) и открыть дополнительное окно, в которое необходимо вывести промежуточную информацию.

```
void MainWindow::foo(){

  for(;;){
    if (a < 0){
      DebugMeshPrint d;
      d.run(); // Запускаю доп. окно. Оно мне нужно для отладки.
      auto break_point = 0; // * тут точка остановки
    }
  }
}
```

Я создал виджет

```
class DebugMeshPrint : public QWidget {
    Q_OBJECT

  public:
    DebugMeshPrint(QWidget* parent = nullptr);
    ~DebugMeshPrint();

  private:
    void run();
};
```

### Суть проблемы

Вся проблема заключается в том, что при срабатывании точки остановки неактивными становятся и основное окно и дополнительное.

### Что мне нужно

Мне бы хотелось, чтобы дополнительное окно было независимым. Т.е. я передал туда всю необходимую информацию и оно существует само по себе.
Чтобы можно было пользоваться доп. окном даже, когда основное неактивно (сработала точка остановки).

Comment: Так нельзя. Точки останова блокируют весь процесс. Если нужно выводить куда-то отладочную информацию, то это можно делать в стандартный вывод, в файл, или любое другое место, не зависящее от текущего процесса.

Comment: если нужно именно окно, то это должна быть отдельная программа